# Insert command not working in sqlite in android studio 2.3.3

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

Hey guys I've been trying to insert some data into a table ive created in android studio heres the code

```
public class admin_manipulation extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText Train_name;
EditText Train_no;
EditText Train_start;
EditText Train_end;
EditText Train_seats;
Button insert;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_manipulation);
    insert=(Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
    Train_name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.trainname);
    Train_no=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.trainno);
    Train_start=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Startlocation);
    Train_end=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.terminationpoint);
    Train_seats=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.seats);

}
public void addrecords(View view)
{
    String str_Train_name=Train_name.getText().toString();
    String str_Train_no=Train_no.getText().toString();
    String str_Train_start=Train_start.getText().toString();
    String str_Train_end=Train_end.getText().toString();
    String str_Train_seats=Train_seats.getText().toString();

    SQLiteDatabase Trains = openOrCreateDatabase("Train_list",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
    Trains.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Train_list(Train_name VARCHAR,Train_no VARCHAR,Train_start VARCHAR, Train_end VARCHAR , Seats_Available VARCHAR );");
    Toast.makeText(admin_manipulation.this, "The Add records Function has been called" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    String temp="INSERT INTO Train_list VALUES("+str_Train_name+","+str_Train_no+","+str_Train_start+","+str_Train_end+","+str_Train_seats+");";
    Toast.makeText(admin_manipulation.this,temp, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Trains.execSQL(temp);
    }
```

When ever i call this activity i get the error message

```
unfortunately db has stopped
```

(db is the name of the app)

so i decided to comment out the line that says

```
Trains.execSQL(temp);
```

and I found that the activity was being executed with no problems what so ever the app didn't crash so I decided to toast the insert query to see if anything was wrong with it.

[image: Inserted Query]

as far as i can tell it looks okay buy as soon as I include

```
Trains.execSQL(temp);
```

In my code the app crashes( temp contains the query i just toasted )

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a smaller scope? E.g. write a few lines of  pure SQLite/MySQL syntax (Which one is it by the way? Why did you tag both?), which cause the same problem without allowing an additional programming language to get in the way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
   SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase( "Train_list.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY , null);
    try {
        final String CREATE_TABLE_TRAIN_LIST = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Train_list ("
                + "ID INTEGER primary key AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + "Train_name VARCHAR,"
                + "Train_no VARCHAR,"
                + "Train_start VARCHAR,"
                + "Train_end VARCHAR,"
                + "Seats_Available VARCHAR);";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_TRAIN_LIST);
        Toast.makeText(admin_manipulation.this, "table created ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        String sql =
            "INSERT or replace INTO Train_list (Train_name, Train_no, Train_start, Train_end, Seats_Available) VALUES(" + str_Train_name + ", " + str_Train_no + ", " + str_Train_start ", " + str_Train_end ", " + str_Train_seats + ")" ;       
                db.execSQL(sql);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thank You This Helped so much im new to this and this helped me understand so much !

Comment: I suggest you to look for SQLite database and queries's syntax before starting the coding. Understand it nicely. There are a ton of resouces in the internet.

Answer (score -1):

You haven't implemented `getWritableDatabase()` method + in your sql query you didn't use single **quotes** `"INSERT INTO Train_list VALUES("+str_Train_name+","+str_Train_no+","+str_Train_start+","+str_Train_end+","+str_Train_seats+");";`

change it to

```
String temp="INSERT INTO Train_list VALUES(" '"+str_Train_name+"'","'"+str_Train_no+"'","'"+str_Train_start+"'","'"+str_Train_end+"'","'"+str_Train_seats+"'");";
```